# Restore TextCursor after paintEvent

Tags: c++, qt, events, text-editor, paint

I am using a subclassed `QPlainTextEditor`, and I'm using a custom `paintEvent` to highlight every second row. Now, the painting works, but the `TextCursor` disappears, and to make things worse, I can't see the typed letters, even in the rows that are not supposed to be painted.
I'm using 
`QPainter painter((QAbstractScrollArea*)(viewport()));` as the painter and 
`painter.fillRect(...);` for painting the row.
Are these the correct functions for this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

what's the code to access to your textcursor? It should be something like this:

```
QTextCursor cursor = textEdit->textCursor();
cursor.insertText(QString(QChar::ObjectReplacementCharacter), svgCharFormat);
textEdit->setTextCursor(cursor);
```

where textEdit is a defined as:

```
QTextEdit *textEdit;
```

you can get/set the QTextDocument with:

```
textEdit->document();
textEdit->setDocument(...);
```